# Debug Apple pay message Payment request is invalid: <private>

Tags: ios, swift, applepay

My app implement Apple Pay and the payment sheet is successfully displayed for some cards like boon virtual cards. With my personal credit card (french credit card), the payment request is invalid.

My code :

```
 let paymentRequest = PKPaymentRequest()
 paymentRequest.merchantIdentifier = "merchant.com.<companyName>"
 paymentRequest.requiredBillingAddressFields = [.name]
 if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    paymentRequest.supportedNetworks = PKPaymentRequest.availableNetworks()
 } else {
    paymentRequest.supportedNetworks = [.masterCard, .visa, .amex]
 }
 paymentRequest.countryCode = "FR"
 paymentRequest.currencyCode = "EUR"
 paymentRequest.paymentSummaryItems = booking.charges.flatMap { 
     PKPaymentSummaryItem(label: $0.label, amount: $0.amount, type: .pending)
 } + [PKPaymentSummaryItem(label: LanguageManager.get(key: "__app_name"), amount: booking.total.amount, type: .pending)]
 if let paymentAuthorizationViewController = PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController(paymentRequest: paymentRequest) as PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController? {
    paymentAuthorizationViewController.delegate = self
    self.present(paymentAuthorizationViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

`paymentAuthorizationViewController` is `nil` and I got a console log `Payment request is invalid: <private>`

How can I debug that and know what is behind this enigmatic `<private>`?

Answer (score 1):

Is the total amount you're trying to charge 0? It looks like it is, but I'm not sure. You can't have a payment request for a zero amount, it needs to be at least greater than zero. You can still mark the summary items as pending, and the amount won't appear to the user.